# Why can't I break blocks in my singleplayer Minecraft Education Edition world?

Tags: minecraft-education-edition

I can't break blocks in Minecraft: Education Edition. I also can't interact with my chest or furnace and I can't attack any mobs. My school doesn't use Minecraft Education Edition but I downloaded it from my school website for learning computer science. Also when I use my school account on a different device, I can break blocks...
If you know how to solve my problem, please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You might have immutable world on. Immutable prevents you from placing and destroy blocks unless you are above a allow block

Answer (score 0):

Your school must have prevented you from breaking blocks.

You must be in creative mode or be a "builder" to break blocks so nobody will grief a school's server (even though you are in single player, it still affects you).

Comment: but I have never use it for school..... and my school doesn't use it. I just found it in my school website....

Comment: Also I created a world that no one have joined. It happens on one device, but when I use it on a different device it works

Comment: @Jmooroof I don’t think the school can prevent you from placing blocks